# CSS: cannot get height transition working

Tags: css, height, transition

I've been struggling with CSS height transitions today.
I'd like to use it in several places in my little project, but I can't get right...

Here is a little widget replicating the solution I'm working on right now: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNhv5/1/)

When clicking the "this is a button", I would like the height transition take place. Before clicking the login form should be hidden. When I set the height value of the form to 0, it behaves really strange. I've looked through some tutorials, which suggest using `max-height`, but I still get awkward results.

When the "this is a button" has been clicked and the full height of the form has been achieved, it should transition its height to 0 or disappear, when clicked the upper button again.

I think transitioning every element inside the form is really a stupid/wrong approach - that's the last thing I can come up with, lol...

I'm out of ideas and couldn't think where to look for possible solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off with, you need to set your form's height to 0, and set it's overflow to hidden so that its contents won't bleed out:

```
form{
 height:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

Now that the transition is setup, you need to define a class that, when applied to the form, will trigger that transition:

```
form.expand{
   height:100px;   
}
```

Unfortunately, you need to define a height in units - using auto won't work.

Now, you need to add some javascript. No way getting around it, stylesheets don't know anything about button clicks:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var form = document.querySelector('#login-form');
    form.className = form.className + ' ' + 'expand';
});
```

This script listens for clicks on the button, and adds the `expand` class to our form dynamically, which triggers the transition.

If you don't like having to code a height measurement for this, `opacity` is a popular alternative.

http://jsfiddle.net/PNhv5/2/

Comment: Since JS is needed anyway, could you get the height, save it to a variable, then set the height to 0 and modify the height on click, or will that not trigger CSS transition?

Comment: It would, and is a valid approach. But, from a readability/maintainability point of view, I prefer applying classes in javascript, not styles, whenever possible.

Comment: Absolutely. Just if the OP, or anyone else, wanted to use `auto` this would be the work around.

Comment: Noooooo.... `auto` won't work. You can only transition through numerics. That's how rendering engines do their transitiony magic.

Comment: Right. I meant that if someone didn't want to define the height, and have the `auto` rendered height used for the transition, you could get that value via JS, store it, set it to 0, etc.

Comment: Ah, now I'm on the trolley. Yes, you can get the computed height, save it to a variable, and perform the transition that way. You'd just need to take care you don't expose your page to a Flash Of Unstyled Content during the process.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Chris! Your solution works like a charm, hehe. I couldn't have figured out the overflow: hidden part!